# extract .dxf data using ezdxf to add to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, ezdxf

The end goal is to extract the text contained on a specific layer, inside of a named view, from the model space. I have the layer restriction (the text in yellow for visual), but I can't seem to figure out the syntax (if possible) to limit the query to either items inside one of the named views, or within a bounding box that I define to match the named view (orange box). The text being queried is single text. It is (and will always be) an exploded table. Each text item has a unique .insert value.

[image]

[image]

Ultimately this above mentioned query loop would be put inside a loop to iterate over all named views (bounding box) inside of the model space. Each of the iterations creating a unique list containing the query results. The list would then be input into a pandas dataframe for further manipulations.

```
import ezdxf

filepath = "C:/MBS_JOBS-16/8741-22/8741-22_(DTL).dxf"
doc = ezdxf.readfile(filepath)
msp = doc.modelspace()

ls = []
for e in msp.query('TEXT MTEXT[layer=="text"]'):
    ls.append(e.dxf.text)

print(ls)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ezdxf` package does not have a feature for selecting entities based on location and size, but a bounding box based implementation is relatively easy.

It is important to know that bounding boxes of text based entities (TEXT, MTEXT) are inaccurate because `matplotlib` (used by `ezdxf` to render text) renders TTF fonts differently than AutoCAD.

I created an example DXF file with 6 views, called "v1", "v2", ...:
[image: view-example]

The following code prints the the content of view "v1": ["Text1a", "Text1b"]

```py
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.math import BoundingBox, Vec2
from ezdxf import bbox


def get_view_box(view):
    center = Vec2(view.dxf.center)
    size = Vec2(view.dxf.width, view.dxf.height)
    bottom_left = center - (size / 2)
    top_right = center + (size / 2)
    return BoundingBox([bottom_left, top_right])


doc = ezdxf.readfile("views.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()

view = doc.views.get("v1")
view_box = get_view_box(view)

for e in msp.query("TEXT MTEXT"):
    text_box = bbox.extents([e])  # expects a list of entities!
    if view_box.contains(text_box):
        print(e.dxf.text)
```